# Merging sequences and files from one project into another in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, video-editor

I have a project that I am working on which required a number of sequences creating in a short time frame. A colleague assisted and I would like to merge his files into the project I am currently working within. The aim is to have well ordered final project with all assets in one place.

There are a number of offline links when I bring the camera footage across from his project. The original file paths are pointing to his local machine.

In Adobe Indesign, there is a feature called "relink to folder" which is very useful to link up multiple missing image links that have been moved to a different location. Is there an equivalent feature in Adobe Premiere Pro? At the time of writing, it appears I need to relink one at a time and I was hoping for a more efficient way to do this. Any suggestions would be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using project , it is because all projects are built on a different system
With its features, the operating system is embedded. Therefore, while running the project on your operating system, you may encounter messages such as the image below, and you must act on the option that you see in the image.

[image]

By clicking this button you can search for your missing files, you can even create a file with missing names and paste it in the project

Also, if you need a sequence, enter the items of one templates in another [premiere pro templates](https://maxeffect.ir/project-primiere/) First you have to run the main project, then import the project from the file menu to get a message like the one below.

[image]

I hope I was able to help
Ask if you have any questions
Good luck